# binding ajax data to jqxGrid

Tags: jquery, ajax, populate, jqxgrid

I have a form which uses submitForm() to send it to the server by ajax Call.

```
    <form id="searchform" onsubmit="return submitForm();">
```

I want the data returned by the this ajax call to populate a jqxGrid.

```
    function submitForm() {
            $.ajax({
                    type:'GET', 
                    url: 'searchresults.php',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: $('#searchform').serialize(), 
                    success: get_ajax_data
            });
            return false;
        }

        function get_ajax_data(data, statusText, xhr) {

        }
```

Just a hint would be enough. I am new to jqxGrid and have seen the demos and prepared my json data accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

jqxGrid data is bound to  local or remote source. If your Ajax submit is populating a database then you would set the source of the jqxGrid to a PHP script or similar which queries the DB to send back the required data.

After you have submitted the data, you can re-set the jqxGrid source to refresh the data.

You can set the cells values manually using the 'setcellvalue' method. But I would recommend the first option of binding the grid to a database.

Comment: Here's the documentation for that: https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxgrid/jquery-grid-datasources.htm